# Show marker on current location in cesium

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I'm showing current location using the below code in cesium 3D map

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Include the CesiumJS JavaScript and CSS files -->
  <script src="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.84/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.84/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
  <div id="toolbar"></div>
  <script>
    // Your access token can be found at: https://cesium.com/ion/tokens.
    // Replace `your_access_token` with your Cesium ion access token.

Cesium.Ion.defaultAccessToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
  imageryProvider: Cesium.createWorldImagery({
    style: Cesium.IonWorldImageryStyle.AERIAL_WITH_LABELS,
  }),
  animation: false,
  timeline: false,
  baseLayerPicker: false,
  fullscreenButton: false,
  infoBox: false,
  sceneModePicker: false,
  navigationHelpButton: false,
  homeButton: false,
  infoBox: false,
  geocoder : false,
});

let label;
var layers = viewer.scene.imageryLayers;
var blackMarble = layers.addImageryProvider(
  new Cesium.IonImageryProvider({ assetId: 3812 })
);

var button = document.createElement('button');
       button.type = 'button';
            button.className = 'cesium-button';
            button.onclick = function() {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(fly);
                }
                else
                {
                console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
                }
            };
            button.textContent = 'Show Location';
            document.getElementById('toolbar').appendChild(button);

const camera = viewer.camera;

function fly(position) {
          if(label){
                viewer.entities.remove(label);
            }
            label = viewer.entities.add({
                position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude),
                label: {
                    text: "Lat: "+position.coords.latitude+", "+"Long: "+position.coords.longitude",
                    scale: 0.8,
                    pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(0, -30),
                    font: "32px Helvetica",
                    fillColor: Cesium.Color.YELLOW,
                    outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
                    outlineWidth: 3,
                    style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL_AND_OUTLINE,
                }
            });

    viewer.camera.flyTo({
      destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(
        position.coords.longitude,
        position.coords.latitude,
        1005.0
      ),
    });



    }

blackMarble.alpha = 0.5;
blackMarble.brightness = 1.2;

  </script>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i want to show a custom market on map with latitude and longitude shown on map rather than simple label as shown in my code.

Sandcastle Link :

[Sandcastle Link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

i want to show latitude and longitude in custom map marker like this screenshot

[image]

One more issue i was facing when i was adding Sandcastle.declare(addBillboard); in my html page i got error in my that Uncaught ReferenceError: Sandcastle is not defined so how will i implement this code in my html page.

Comment: You should include Sandcastle-header.js.
Please have a look at https://github.com/3DGISKing/CesiumJsSamples/blob/master/0-HelloWorld/index.html

Comment: @ZhefengJin: Can you please create a sandcastle for the custom marker i tried the above but it is not working