# Background image not changed in Cesium Map

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I want to change background image of sky providing custom image but it is not changing

```
var scene = viewer.scene;
scene.skyBox = new Cesium.SkyBox({
sources : {
positiveX : 'images/galaxy.jpg',
negativeX : 'images/galaxy.jpg',
positiveY : 'images/galaxy.jpg',
negativeY : 'images/galaxy.jpg',
positiveZ : 'images/galaxy.jpg',
negativeZ : 'images/galaxy.jpg',
}
});
```

In local system i have given these path but in sandcastle demo i have not added image.

[Sandcastle Link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=hVFNa8MwDP0rJpdmEBx27dIw1utgh8JYRy5qomZaHTvYTtps7L9PTjvYR7v4IvT09N5D7sGKnnCPViyExr1YoqOukY8jFhdROfZLoz2QRltEiXgvdKFBUwOejJ6LLSiHSQA9NaiYdsIC9HF1E0rPPq5EjWxz9JNjy8OxSrcb7szhZ4jViMXs50xnOYmYB/PWOPLU4xO3M05Ro0trUHAY5GtbzziJxhr+Z3xprCc11pMaz5Malxl8oNOVoiTKnB8U5oUW47ulpjXWi86qWMrUY9Mq8Cyx6codelk6F44bqFn6fTWrqBdULc78nigVOMeTbafUit6wiPIsZf6fVWWgIl0/9GgVDIH2cp3fH0EpZZZye37TG6M2YH8pfwI)

Any suggestions, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that image URLs are correct.
See this [Sandcastle link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=pZLNTsMwEIRfxcqlRapsIW4lrRC9gkCqhADl4ibb1K2zjvyTJkW8O5u0VBB6Cr7YO96d+Q5bScsqBXuwbMYQ9mwBToWCv3TaOInSrl4Y9FIh2CSasI8EE5SoCumVwSlbS+1g0opeFaCp7aS10ufVbXtVlONSQKCYYx7vSvrsbu52zb2pf0MsO21Mec4ESyRs2oaXximvKnilcrTxvnRTIfzGAmwdNzYXUMui1OCEh9oHS480rEA8S7u7eYRMlDXflvmIkBFy+S8rPFt9U70Npmr6VIOtsOlTvQ+mOvSpBlvh2YrW4rQb0SSKnW80zBNk3blTRWmsZ8HqMefkRZ7Sk9kqpDvwPHWuXam2NRY/R+NMVUxlsws7y1ItnaOfddB6qQ6QRPNYUP+fUW1kpjB/qsBq2bRtm+v5w1HknMeCysuT3hi9krbn/AU)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer Can you please answer this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089742/show-marker-on-current-location-in-cesium